# VB6: How to switch to pixels instead of twips

Tags: vb6

I am refactoring a VB6 application. The measurements of any of the controls are in twips. Is it possible in VB6 to set a control to use **pixels** instead of **twips**? Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to do this for a single control or for every control at the same time?

Comment: @Justin, thanks for your comment. I am particularly interested in how to do this for a form with child controls.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I worked extensively with scalemode back in the day and all I can say is don't bother. It wasn't properly universally supported, which meant that you'll end up converting back to twips for some things anyway.

VB6 is twips based, like it or not, so if you try to do things pixel based, you'll be fighting the current the whole way.

Fortunately VB.net finally ended all that, and is completely pixel based, you can still alter you viewport scaling but .net seems to handle that much better than Vb6.

Answer (score 7):

Does the [ScaleMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445668%28VS.60%29.aspx) help?

> Returns or sets a value indicating the unit of measurement for coordinates of an object when using graphics methods or when positioning controls.

Comment: Please add the actual answer

Answer (score 7):

```
dim iInPixels as integer
dim iInTwips as integer

iInPixels = 200
iInTwips  = iInPixels * Screen.TwipsPerPixelX
iInPixels = iInTwips / Screen.TwipsPerPixelX
```

As @drventure said, you'll be rowing against the current the whole way, but it really isn't all that bad, as long as you can isolate the logic to a single spot.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft Knowledge Base article:  [How to Convert Twips to Pixels](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210590)

The link above is for Access VBA but will work with VB6 as well.  I'm not aware of native VB6 functionality to do what you need.  From what I remember ScaleMode will not work for what you want to do (despite the fact that it seems to exist to solve your exact problem).

**EDIT**: As I'm thinking about it, ScaleMode did not solve **my** problem that I had at the time.  Depending on what you are trying to do, it may solve **your** problem just fine.  I'd certainly try that first since it will produce simpler, more maintainable code.

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way. 
I got the Twips from Form1.Picture.Width and by dividing with pixelize you get pixels ANYWHERE in VB6 Script. 
In General Declarations
**Const pixelize As Double = 26.45833333**

**Command3.Caption = "Pixels: " & Int(Form1.Picture.Width / pixelize) & "x" & Int(Form1.Picture.Height / pixelize)**

Works for me, maybe you are helped.